# Can you reload two crossbows with Aegis Greater Extra Arms or having multiple arms and Crossbow Mastery feat in the same round?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

Can you reload two crossbows with Aegis Greater Extra Arms or having multiple arms and Crossbow Mastery feat in the same round?

> **Extra Arms, Greater**:
>   The extra arms on the aegis’s astral suit function at nearly the same capacity as his normal arms. Each arm can now wield or use a light or one-handed weapon, shield, or any other item that he could normally use. Alternatively, the aegis can use one or both arms when wielding a two-handed weapon, possibly allowing him to wield a pair of two-handed weapons. The circumstance bonus on Climb checks and CMD against grapple attempts increases to +3 per extra arm that is not holding anything. The aegis must be 8th level and have the Extra Arms and Lesser Extra Arms customizations before selecting this customization.

and

[Crossbow Mastery](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/crossbow-mastery-combat/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, yes this would allow you to wield/reload two crossbows at once.

Specifically, from Extra Arms, Greater:

> Alternatively, the aegis can use one or both arms when wielding a two-handed weapon, possibly allowing him to wield a pair of two-handed weapons.

[Crossbows](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/crossbow-heavy) are a weapon that can be wielded in two hands. Reloading them is now a [Free Action](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/crossbow-mastery-combat/).

By logic, you also have enough arms to use both. Your "real" hands would probably be holding the crossbows while your Aegis arms perform the assisting things such as locking in the bolts and steadying the weapons. This is no different than providing the extra hand necessary for you to wield two greatswords or similar.